# unshortening urls

Tags: c#, vb.net, url-shortener

I am trying to unshorten urls and have not been able to find code (vb.net/c#) to  do this. These are the twitter shortened urls and I guess I could try and access one of the web services available and do a httpwebrequest but would prefer to find some programmatic way of doing this.

Comment: How is using an `HttpWebRequest` to access a web service not programmatic? You write a program to use that class, don't you?

Comment: Any approach you take will necessarily involve performing a query against some external API.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get it directly from response of the shortened url  since it will return a status code `MovedPermanently` and the location for the real url.(This should work for most of the sites without the need for navigating to the real url)

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://t.co/xqbLEi6s");
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
var resp = req.GetResponse();
string realUrl = resp.Headers["Location"];
```

Other test data: `http://goo.gl/zdf2n` , `http://tinyurl.com/8xc9vca` , `http://x.co/iEup`, `http://is.gd/vTOlz6` ,  `http://bit.ly/FUA4YU`

Comment: Or you can allow auto redirect and get real URL from the resp.ResponseUri property:
`HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://t.co/xqbLEi6s");
var resp = req.GetResponse();
string realUrl = resp.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;`

Comment: @Yuriy Why should I load the whole(possibly big) page when I can do it with a small response.

Comment: I haven't thought about this, you are right, your code is much more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

There is no magic way to unshorten a URL without asking the service which created the URL (and the way to ask will be different for each service), or more pragmatically, just opening the URL and watching where it redirects to.